# How to revert a vertical numpy array (1D) to its usual horizontal default form?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Ok, it has been asked many times how to convert a 1D numpy array to a vertical one. The most used option is, if

```
In [2]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

we usually do:

```
In [5]: a = a[ : , np.newaxis]
In [6]: a
Out[6]:
array([[1],
     [2],
     [3],
     [4]])
```

because we know that `a.T` doesn't work (something that people with a more math background that CS, like me, find a little bit shocking...).

My question is, if you receive an array (1D), that is already vertical, how do you transform it to horizontal?

Comment: Ok, after finishing writing this, I have found the option `a.ravel()` that erases all the [ ] exceot the exterior ones. This would solve my problem but I suppose there has to be another not so dramatic option...

Comment: There is also `np.squeeze(a)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such thing as a horizontal or vertical 1D array in numpy.  A 1D array is just a 1D array.  It is OK if you want to call a 2D array with shape, `(4, 1)`, a "vertical" array.  Then a 2D array with shape, `(1, 4)`, would be a "horizontal" array.  In that case the transpose will work as you expect it should.

The transpose `a[:, np.newaxis].T` gives a horizontal array with shape, `(1, 4)`.  You can always check the shape of arrays with `print(a.shape)`.  If you want to go back to a 1D array, you can call `a.squeeze()`, which will return an array with shape, `(4,)`.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print("Array {0} has shape {1}.".format(a, a.shape))

print(a[:, None].shape)
print((a[:, None].T).shape)
print(a[:, None].squeeze().shape)
```

Returns,

```
Array [1 2 3 4] has shape (4,).
(4, 1)
(1, 4)
(4,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Along side the `np.squeeze()` that removes the single-dimensional entries from the shape of an array, you can use [`np.hstack()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) (Stack arrays in sequence horizontally) or `np.concatenate()` along the second axis.

```
>>> a
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
>>> np.hstack(a)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.concatenate(a, axis=1)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```